# Cygwin - can't run ruby command

Tags: ruby, linux, unix, cygwin

When I run `ruby -v` in cygwin, it shows me the ruby which I have installed in windows. FYI - I never installed any ruby as a part of my cygwin installation.

But when I run `gem list`, I get the error:

```
 /cygdrive/c/ruby/bin/gem: 
 C:/dev/ruby/bin/ruby.exe^M: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

I Googled and found this problem a lot. But there is no one who explained what it means and why it happens. Can someone please answer those questions for me and help me to fix this problem?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Under cygwin, your best bet is to run the cygwin version of ruby, installed using the cygwin setup tool.

You *can* use regular ruby, but you will have interoperability issues like this.

What you are seeing here is the shell complaining about a `^M` at the end of the "shebang" line of the `gem` script (first line that tells it what interpreter to use). This `^M` is an artefact of the windows environment where all lines end with this character as well as just the newline character that unix uses on its own.

You could solve this problem by removing the newlines e.g. by using `dos2unix` command on `gem` but it won't be long before you run into further issues ...

Comment: Then, I think I am SOL. I needed cygwin to use the taza gem in windows. It asks me to use cygwin because the windows versions of Taza cywin commands will not work because windows sucks. I did not listen to the doc author and got stuck in the middle steps. Now, even cygwin seems to be useless. What do I do ? Instructions at bottom of page - https://github.com/scudco/taza/wiki/Getting-Started Should I just do all those unix commands on a linux vm and copy paste the project created by the commands into windows machine ?

Comment: Can you use the Cygwin version of ruby?

Comment: No. I need to use the ruby on windows with its set of special gems.

Comment: So why are you using Cygwin exactly? Could u use mingw?

Comment: ok - i'll try that as well, but the tutorial for taza gem suggests that i use cygwin to create taza projects on windows. https://github.com/scudco/taza/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: Yeah I saw that. It doesn't say why though. Hopefully, it is just a case of the  scripting commands. If the taza binaries themselves actually *do* depend on cygwin then you are indeed boned. You're using some other library that requires the win32 extensions, right?

Comment: actually, i am a newbie. I don't even know what is happening. I am just trying to setup a project and learn taza without getting into internals for now.

Comment: If that's the case, forget about the native win32 ruby and use the cygwin version. Run the `setup` program available from cygwin.org - after the first few screens you'll get to a giant list of programs. Filter for 'ruby' and you'l see the ruby runtime come up. Select this and complete the installer and you'll have ruby available in the cygwin environment (which won't have the same problem with paths) next time you run the bash shell. If necessary remove the win32 version from your `PATH`.